# Changing tick labels with plotnine

Tags: python, pandas, plotnine

I'm using [plotnine](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine) to generate a scatterplot where the x-axis is pandas.Timestamp objects.

Currently, the x tick labels (e.g., "2017-07-01") are running into each other. I'd like to be able to do an arbitrary transformation of the tick labels. How do I change the x tick labels on the plot?

It looks like I could do something like `+ scale_x_continuous(labels=???)` but I don't know what argument to pass to labels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked this question as an [issue](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/34) on the plotnine project, and got this as the solution:

```
from mizani.breaks import date_breaks
from mizani.formatters import date_format

...
+ scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks('1 year'), labels=date_format('%Y'))
```

This would also do it:

```
+ scale_x_datetime(labels=lambda lst: [x.year if x.month==1 and x.day==1 else "" for x in lst])
```